# How to get data for _links in nextjs external api call

Tags: node.js, axios, nestjs, hateoas

I am calling an api in my nestjs application. The response of api has hateoas format like below

[image]

and here is my code

```
import { HttpService, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class IqProductQuantityService {
    constructor(
        private readonly httpService: HttpService
    ) {}

...
return this.httpService
                    .get<any>(url, {
                        headers: {
                            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
                        }
                    })
                    .pipe(
                        map((res) => res.data),
                        tap((data) => console.log(data)),
                        tap((data) => console.log(data?._links?._next))
                    );
```

The problem is when I get data, I receive **Array of items**, and there is no _links or _embeded data in the response, seems the axios or nestjs is parsing this data gracefuly to make the life easier, but at same time we lost the information of `_links.next` to do paging

This is what I receive:
`console.log(data):`

```json
[
  {
    Id: '82cf8651-c742-4352-aa70-001ee180707c',
    CompanyId: 13279,
    EntityId: 22235,
    IsSerialized: false,
    IsDropShippable: false,
    IsLot: false,
    QuantityInStock: 0,
    QuantityOnOrder: 0,
    QuantityTransferIn: 0,
    QuantityTransferOut: 0,
    UnitId: 0
  },
  {
    Id: '82cf8651-c742-4352-aa70-001ee180707c',
    CompanyId: 13279,
    EntityId: 22236,
    IsSerialized: false,
    IsDropShippable: false,
    IsLot: false,
    QuantityInStock: 0,
    QuantityOnOrder: 0,
    QuantityTransferIn: 0,
    QuantityTransferOut: 0,
    UnitId: 0
  },
  {
    Id: '82cf8651-c742-4352-aa70-001ee180707c',
    CompanyId: 13279,
    EntityId: 22237,
    IsSerialized: false,
    IsDropShippable: false,
    IsLot: false,
    QuantityInStock: 0,
    QuantityOnOrder: 0,
    QuantityTransferIn: 0,
    QuantityTransferOut: 0,
    UnitId: 0
  }
]
```

`console.log(data?._links?._next)`:
`undefined`

The question is how should I retrieve `_links.next.href` data?

Comment: How is this.httpService defined? Seems like you are using RxJS's .pipe/map/tap.

Comment: @JonathanRosa it's nestjs HttpService which is using axios under neath, I update the question

Comment: I'm a bit confused - does the output of `console.log(data)` refer to the json-array in your question? Or is it the output of `console.log(data?._links?._next)`?

Comment: Seems like the problem happens before the NestJS controller returns. I recreated the setup, returning that object (and array) in the NestJS controller, and curl and axios saw the underscored attributes.

Comment: @eol I updated, sorry for confusion

Comment: @JonathanRosa I am not returning the result in the controller, trying to use the data in the service. This format of data is called `hateoas` and seems axios or nest is parsing it to be easier to use

Comment: @Reza I meant your nest-side code, not your client service. What's happening there? Neither NestJS nor axios is stripping away the underscored attributes.

Comment: @JonathanRosa ok, let me create stackblitz to reproduce and share

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying to reproduce the issue I found the root cause. I write it here in case someone else has same problem and finding this post.

I found when I call the api in postman the response has `Content_type: application/hal+json` header, and in postman in request header we have `Accept:*/*`

If you change it `Accept:application/json` you will receive the array of data (like what I received in my code)

So what I did I changed my code to below and now I get all _link information on `res.data`

```
return this.httpService
                    .get<any>(url, {
                        headers: {
                            Accept: 'application/hal+json',
                            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
                        }
                    })
```